Typescript error "No Overload matches this call" in inquirer.prompt
I am working on a little assignment, and wrote a few lines of code. The code is working fine, however I see this error which is kind of irritating:
import inquirer from "inquirer";
import chalk from "chalk";

let answers = await inquirer.prompt({
    name: "age",
    type: "number",
    message: "Enter your Age:"}
);

In the above code, there is a red line below "message" and it says this:
enter image description here
Please guide me what is wrong and how this can be fixed.
Thank you
Zeeshan
I tried updating NPM, TypeScript, Inquirer, and I have installed types@inquirer.

I'm not familiar with inquirer but it seems from the message that "prompt" doesn't want an object. Try wrapping it in an array.
let answers = await inquirer.prompt([{
    name: "age",
    type: "number",
    message: "Enter your Age:"}
]);

Ok, i tried it myself. And sure enough there seems to be a problem with the typedef files. But let's use the right package instead and it works fine :)
use:
npm install @inquirer/prompts
npm install @types/inquirer

and the code
import { number } from '@inquirer/prompts';

let answers = await number({
    message: "Enter your Age:"
});

Follow documentation from their github page
https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js

no that didnt solve it but gives error on all the lines of object if I add the [ ] like you mentioned.
